# Differential operators acting on the Schwartz space

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, topological-vector-spaces, schwartz-space

I was asking me the following question and cannot find any answer to it. Any help/suggestion is most than welcome!
Let $D$ be a linear differential operator with polynomial coefficients on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus

$$\displaystyle D=\sum_{\lvert \alpha\rvert\leqslant k} P_\alpha(x) \frac{\partial^{\lvert \alpha\rvert}}{\partial x^\alpha}$$

where the $P_\alpha$'s are polynomial functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider $D$ as an endomorphism of the space of Schwartz functions $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. My question is now the following:

Is the image of $D$ a closed subspace of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (for its natural Frechet topology)?